# applicationContext.xml validation error in spring 4.3?

Tags: xml, spring

3. My **applicationContext.xml**

   is giving validation error. Even the simple xml file is giving the same error.

> My applicationContext.xml is as below :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd">      
    

</beans>
```

The error is :-

> cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

I have googled and tried to resolve this issue but none worked. kindly help me if there is a solution. Thanking you.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Maybe an encoding issue or an issue with invisible character. Did you write this from scratch or did you copy it from somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what happened and why my code gave me lot of problems at the time of posting. I have spent 24 hours on that issue but the immediate next day it is working fine without any changes. Sorry for troubling.